# Non Existence of matrices $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $(I-(AB-BA))^n=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Question is to Prove:

Non Existence of matrices $A,B\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$ such that $(I-(AB-BA))^n=0$.

This question has already been asked already but then i am asking for clarification of another solution i have tried on my own.

First of all $I-(AB-BA)=0$ does not have solution because of trace property.

Now, I Would let $C=AB-BA$ and consider $(C-I)^n=0$

Now, Minimal polynomial of $C$ would be $(x-1)^m$ for some $m\leq n$ and $m\neq 1$

so I would consider jordan form for this...

I would end up with the case that jordan form of $C$ (some of would be jordan blocks with entries in the diagonal $1$ and rest of the rows would just be )would be

$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0&0&\cdots& 0\\ 0&1&1&0&\cdots& 0\\ 0&0&1&1&\cdots& 0\\ 0&0&0&1&\cdots& 0\\ -&-&-&-&-&-\\0&0&0&0&\cdots &
1\end{bmatrix}\\$$

So, Trace of Jordan form of $C$ would be $n$.

thus for the same reason as why $AB-BA=I$ have no solution we now conlcude that :

$(I-(AB-BA))^n=0$ is not satisfied by any matrices.

I have used that Trace of $A$ would be same as Trace of $CAC^{-1}$ for any $C$.

Not very sure if i can use this..

I would be thankful if some one can confirm if what i have done is sufficient/correct.

Thank you.

Comment: I believe your argument to be correct. $AB - BA$ would have all eigenvalues $1$, so you just need to use the fact the you can put it in triangular form (with the eigenvalues on the diagonal), and that the trace is invariant under conjugation.

Comment: yes that is how i have done except that i am not sure of the fact that trace is invariant under conjugation :O

Comment: You know that $\operatorname{trace}(AB) = \operatorname{trace}(BA)$, so $\operatorname{trace}(CAC^{-1}) = \operatorname{trace}(C^{-1} CA) = \operatorname{trace}(A)$.

Even better, the trace is one of the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial, so it's invariant under conjugation, as the polynomial is.

Comment: i could now realize that trace is invariant under conjugation thank you,

Comment: yes yes i was thinking of same justification but your justification with respect to characteristic polynomial makes much more sense to me.. :) Thank you so much :)

Comment: You're welcome!